# How can i set different language for 2 different domain?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

How can i set different language for 2 different domain?
I have 2 different domain for single drupal installation 
**www.example.en 

www.example.fr**
i want to display 2 different language based on the user coming from any domain?

Answer (score 0):

- Go to http://example.com/admin/config/regional/language/configure
- Enable URL
- Save
- Go to Configure
- Select Domain

Keep configuring it all.

Comment: I have tried that, but language not switching based on that.